# I have a 1999 chevy blazer back wheel getting hot

Tags: brakes, chevrolet, troubleshooting, blazer

The back wheel on the passenger side of the blazer is getting very hot, does not make any noise. The brake rotor the hub and the outside of the wheel will be hot after about 3 miles.

Comment: My first guess would be a stuck parking brake.

Answer (score 2):

As Barbecue says, it's almost certainly a stuck brake, either the parking brake or the service brake (i.e. the footbrake). If you jack the car up (having chocked the front wheels first!), you'll probably find the wheel is very hard to turn by hand (compare it with the one on the other side, which should turn freely).

If it is the parking brake (most likely), you should be able to free it off by working the mechanism a few times at the wheel end. If it's the service brake, the most likely culprits are the caliper sliders - these can be freed off with brute force, and either cleaned up or replaced.